# Adding Objects An existing Array

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have an array of users in my app delegate, and in one of the screens I am trying to create an object to add to that array. The user attributes are only an email and a password. On the screen I have two text fields and a button. I want it so that when the button is pressed it generates a new user from what was entered into the fields and places that into the array of users in the app delegate.

Sorry learning the stack overflow interface atm. I'm working with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender:(ContactViewController *)controller 
{
    Person *newPerson = [Person personWithEmail:controller.usernameTextField.text password:controller.passwordTextField.text]; 
    [self.(Truck_Tracker_AppAppDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).listPeople addObject:newPerson];
}
```

I think I've created the Person object newPerson successfully, I'm just having trouble getting it to the app delegate.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Wait, what exactly is your question then?

Comment: -(IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender:(ContactViewController *)controller 
{
    Person *newPerson = [Person personWithEmail:controller.usernameTextField.text password:controller.passwordTextField.text]; 
   
    [self.(Truck_Tracker_AppAppDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).listPeople addObject:newPerson];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an array then it can be either a `NSArray` or a `NSMutableArray`.

The first one is *immutable*, you cannot add elements to an existing `NSArray`, you can just create a new one with an added element.

In this first case you should do something similar to

```
self.array = [array arrayByAddingObject:newUser];
```

If it's a `NSMutableArray` then you can easily add the item by doing

```
[self.array addObject:newUser];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your using just a standard NSArray when you want to be using a NSMutableArray.

Check out the docs on it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:@"some data"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample on the Apple Developer Site:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSTableViewBinding/Introduction/Intro.html

does pretty much what you describe.  It should be easy to modify to do exactly what you want.